# Subquery with order by random does not work on database with 500.000.000 rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-order-by, window-functions

I want to perform an update query on a offline database with DB Browser for SQLite.

I tested my query on a few rows and its working perfectly there, but not with my database which has 500.000.000 rows +. It looks like the random subquery is not executed at all there and the first rows of the group by are taken.

The query:

```
UPDATE  
table
SET typ = 3 WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM()
  )  
  WHERE typ = 1 GROUP BY idg HAVING COUNT(idg) > 5
)
```

Sample data:

```
id |idg| typ
1  | 1 | 1
2  | 1 | 1
3  | 1 | 1
4  | 1 | 1
5  | 1 | 1
6  | 1 | 1
7  | 1 | 1
8  | 2 | 1
9  | 2 | 1
10 | 2 | 1
11 | 2 | 1
12 | 2 | 1
13 | 2 | 1
14 | 2 | 1
15 | 2 | 1
```

Is there any fix or workaround to execute my query successfully ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. First ORDER BY cannot be used in a sub query second even if it could what impact do you expect it to have? Without limiting the number of rows returned the order has no bearing on how rhis query executes and what values are returned from the sub query.

Comment: @engineersmnky    This query should update 1 row randomly from group by idg. Which works well on my test database with ~50 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+, you can use the [`UPDATE ... FROM...`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax, so that you can *join* to the table a query that uses window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to check if a specific `idg` has more than 5 rows and returns a random `id`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idg ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn
  FROM tablename
  WHERE typ = 1
)
UPDATE tablename AS t
SET typ = 3 
FROM cte AS c
WHERE t.id = c.id AND c.rn = 6; -- rn = 6 makes sure that there are at least 6 rows
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=cdbfcfff1e950f00f819c68da79e2519).

For SQLite 3.25.0+ use the operator `IN` with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET typ = 3 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idg ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn
    FROM tablename
    WHERE typ = 1
  )
  WHERE rn = 6 -- rn = 6 makes sure that there are at least 6 rows 
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=3a742c156659a89c6ecca35c9230312a).

Comment: My query inside db Browser on low data has worked but not on dbfiddle.uk strangely. I will try your query thanks.
May can you tell me if one of both querys is faster ? Im on 3.33.0+.
EDIT: and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user5441400 the 1st query should perform better, but for a dataset of 500.000.000 rows +, which is huge for SQLite I suggest that you try them both and  also try indexing on idg and typ.